# print uninitialized variable can be devastating for a code?

Tags: variables, printing, compiler-errors, gfortran

I seem to have met with a weird issue with gfortran compiler. For a variable I didn't assign a value but I printed it on the screen, this operation might mess up with memory usage even if I didn't use that variable in the actual coding. Can anybody help me with this? The followings are the more detailed questions relevant to this issue.

(1) how to direct warning messages to a file instead of printing on screen by default? It could be gfortran does output uninitialized variable as warning on the screen, but I cannot read them. But still, by default or even when I force it with -finit-local-zero, all the local variables are initialized, why would there still be this uninitialization related issue?

(2) how to trap this issue of usage of uninitialized variables in gfortran? It seems intel ifort compiler can do so by trapping it with error message. I looked through the compilation options, but could not find an appropriate one. Maybe somebody who is familiar with gfortran can help me on it.

(3) Can anybody explain to me why an irrelevant statement printing something on screen thus supposedly affecting nothing in the execution should have such a devastating effect on the code?

Comment: Could you show some example code?  Not all variables which could be initialized are local, say, so we can't comment on that unless we understand where you have problems.

Comment: it would be composed of several quite big files, and the issue is kind of sporadic, so I cannot upload it. In my case, when the frequency partition is set at 20, it works fine, when it is set at 40, then the issue appears. Intel compiler ifort is able to recognize uninitialized variable as to be an error, which gives me a feeling that intel has noticed the dangerous behavior of uninitialized variables, but gfortran does not seem to have similar functionality.

Comment: I think the questions raised above is not closely related to debugging the code, but instead quite general about specific knowledge points. Thus, hopefully there can be answers to the specific questions.

Comment: Ultimately, it is due to hidden memory access issue. I have tried to use valgrind or drmemory to detect the issue. If not successful, then I have to rewrite the whole thing from fresh. Anybody has a better way to debug this type segmentation error?

Comment: to direct warning message to file, ./a.exe 2> err > out can do the trick. Now error message is sent to err file while screen output is in out.